# Woocommerce - link to category of products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with custom link to my specific category. 
I wanted to show in the link product cat "shoes", unfortunately the link does not work.

`<?php $category_link = get_term_by('slug', 'product_cat', 'shoes');
?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="xxx">Shoes</a>`

Comment: [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) is use to get the term detail; and you are calling in wrongly. it should be `get_term_by('slug', 'shoes', 'product_cat');` and it'll return term detail and then you have to call `get_term_link()`. So it's better to directly call `get_term_link('shoes', 'product_cat')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use get_term_link(), like this:

`$category_link = get_term_link('shoes', 'product_cat');`

You can use slug or category ID too for the first parameter.